# Django: Queryset.clear() method on OneToOneField()

Tags: django, django-models

I need to avoid cascading deletes on a foreign key, but it's a OneToOneField(), like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    def delete(self):
        self.mysubmodel.clear()  # Breaks because self.cartitem is not a QuerySet.
        super(MyModel, self).delete()

class MySubModel(models.Model):
    mymodel = models.OneToOneField(MyModel)
```

This version would work (but I can't use this version):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    def delete(self):
        self.mysubmodel_set.clear()  # Works because self.mysubmodel_set is a QuerySet.
        super(MyModel, self).delete()

class MySubModel(models.Model):
    mymodel = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the field to None in the delete method should work:

```
self.mysubmodel = None
```

Comment: And that won't cause any problems down the road?

Answer (score 0):

What is expected behavior here? I mean, o2o does not allow null values?

Comment: You can't use null=True in a OneToOneField()?

Comment: The behavior is that I'm creating a sub item that will be based off an item, but the subitem has a dependent and therefore can't be deleted unless it's dependent is deleted, so I can't just have subitems being deleted because a item goes.